# GHDL Installation on Mac OS

Tags: macos, vhdl, ghdl

I'm trying to install the latest release of GHDL on MacOS (v0.35).

I previously had installed 0.29 that is the one that HomeBrew installs but that version is giving me some problems so I need to upgrade.

I downloaded the tar file from the releases webpage and saw that it contained 3 folders: `lib`, `include` and `bin`.

I just copied the content of those folders to `/usr/local/{folder}` (folder being `bin`, `include` or `lib`) but I guess I'm missing something because I get an error saying that GHDL can't find `std` library.

```
ghdl:warning: library std does not exists for v93
ghdl:warning: library ieee does not exists for v93
ghdl:error: cannot find "std" library
```

I am guessing that it is a path related issue because if I run GHDL from the download folder:

```
path/to/download/folder/bin/ghdl -a my_file.vhd
```

it works.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does `ghdl -a -v my_file.vhd` report? Is this a mcode, GCC or LLVM backend? Maybe it's better to discuss such an issue in Gitter: https://gitter.im/ghdl1/Lobby or as a new issue on GitHub.

Comment: I saw your gitter thread and can duplicate your problem. It has to do with permissions in /usr/local/lib when copying the ghdl directory and it's subdirectories and contents to /usr/local/lib. I corrected the issue by `cd /usr/local/lib; sudo chmod -R ugo+r ghdl` which will make all the /usr/local/lib/ghdl subdirectories and contents readable by anyone. You've already demonstrated /usr/bin/ghdl is readable by you, it'd be worth checking /usr/include/vpi_user.h is also world readable.

Comment: New files/directories created by an effective ID of root from sudo have permissions derived from the union of a umask specified by launchd. If you `cd /usr/local/lib` and `sudo touch foo` you'll see file foo has owner rw access only. Remove that and `sudo mkdir foo` you'll see directory foo has group other execute permission but not read or write permission.

Comment: @user1155120 Can you motivate why you re-added the VHDL tag? The question is not about VHDL code or VHDL coding. The relevant tags: `ghdl` and `macos` are already there. One could question if this question is actually really on-topic for StackOverflow: it would be better suited on some GHDL support forum or SuperUser stack exchange. Or a personal question to you, as you seem to handle Mac OS builds of GHDL...

Comment: @JHBonarius - You could pursue whether this is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) noting [tag:ghdl] is a VHDL compiler, the [tag:vhdl] tag is active on SO, and there are no close votes. The ghdl build in question [ghdl-0.35-mcode-macosx.tgz](https://github.com/tgingold/ghdl/releases). Any insinuation aside I am not involved in ghdl [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/) builds nor is the question upvote mine.